# Optimizing google script value retrieval

Tags: javascript, optimization, google-apps-script, google-sheets, getvalue

I have a "database" sheet - 60 columns wide by 100,000 rows.

On my other sheet I have one column (V) that specifies rows on that database sheet and I need to display corresponding values from specific database columns in a different column (T).

So, I tried to write a custom function, which takes in all values in V, retrieves values from the database, and fills them down in T. 
E.g. in T3, I would have =myFunction(V3:V100)

Then, my script for loops through each cell in V and does something like this: (*people_sheet = my database sheet; row = the number value in each V cell)

```
output_array[i] = people_sheet.getRange(row, last_name_col_num, 1, 1).getValue() + " (" + people_sheet.getRange(row, first_name_col_num, 1, 1).getValue() + ")" + people_sheet.getRange(row, suffix_specifier_wikipedia, 1, 1).getValue();
```

I then return the output_array, and the idea is that it fills down col T from T3.

I have discovered that this is extremely inefficient, and the script times out with an Error (unless I reduce the call to something like myFunction(V3:V4);

I read through the optimization pages from Google, but nothing addresses the problem of getting values from a table.

Would anyone be able to suggest a way to address this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being avoiding "getRange" and "getValue" calls entirely. They seem to be extremely inefficient in accessing data on google sheets.

I ended up rewriting my function to actually accept my database as a range, adding a new parameter:
=myFunction(V3:V207, People1!F1:H100000)

inside the function:

```
output_array[i] = people_sheet_FGH_array[row][last_name_col_num - col_F_index] + " (" + people_sheet_FGH_array[row][first_name_col_num - col_F_index] + ")" + people_sheet_FGH_array[row][suffix_specifier_wikipedia - col_F_index];
```

Note that I don't import all 60 columns. (Actually, I had to reduce that number to 20, because I ran into the 2,000,000 cell limit from "new" google sheets and spread it over multiple sheets). I only import those that would be used by this function. (Luckily they are adjacent. If that weren't the case, I would probably create another "helper" sheet, bunching up all the columns I need together through referencing.)